# Excell formula for multiple pasts without repeating previous cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a data set for 12 years of 4,380 days. I want to take the sum of each week. when I make a formula `{=SUM(A1:A7)}` and drag to drop button to the next cell it shows {=SUM(A2:A8)}. This is not what I want for my next cell. Instead I need `{=SUM(A8:A14)`. I can not type this formula the whole way down. It takes a lot of time.

Is there any shorter way of multiple pasting without repeating previous cells?

Comment: only the above formula

Comment: can you upload a file with similar sample data so I can help you better.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a date field (say in Column B) you could use `=indirect()` and some math on `row()` to get the ranges you need for your sum formula. Put this in Row 1 of whatever column you are using: `=SUM(INDIRECT("A" & (ROW()-1) * 7 + 1 & ":" & "A" & ROW()*7))`

That's convoluted as hell, but it will calculate your ranges A1:A7, A8:A14, etc. automatically as you copy that formula down the rows.

If there is a date for each of these numbers (say in column B) then you could do some magic with `sumproduct`, `sumif`, or something like that.

Comment: But I'm sorry I could not make a science of the formula. like those ":" and those blanks. It just got me confuse. I am trying and will keep trying to figure it out. But I will be happy if you could make it simple for me. Thanks

Comment: to break this formula down to understand it try looking at the output of the individual parts. In seperate columns put the following `=Row()*7`, `=Row()-1 * 7 + 1`, and `=INDIRECT("A" & (ROW()-1) * 7 + 1 & ":" & "A" & ROW()*7)`. You'll see that the `=Row()*something` formula is just figuring out which rows are included in the week based off of the current row that the formula is in. The indirect is concatenating those rows into a raange like `A1:A7`. Then the `=Sum()` formula is just summing that range. It's ugly, I will admit, but it's as simple as it can be.